# Facing problems performing string operations in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I would like to let everyone know that I am totally new to C# and Object oriented programming.

Also, can anyone please show me another way to solve the question?

The question which I tried to execute is this :

```
Class Formatter

Formatter()
```

Formatting of strings is done in the constructor.

```
CapitalizeLetter(this string)
```

This method capitalizes the letters entered by the user according to the conditions given. The first letter of the passed string should be capitalized. If the string contains any space or full stop, the next letter should also be capitalized. All the other letters should be in lower cases.

**For example: ajaY malik. k**

**Output : Ajay Malik. K**
The code I tried doing in Formatter class as specified:

```
public static class Formatter
{
    static Formatter()
    {

    }

    public static string CapitalizeLetter(this string value)
    {
        string output = null;
        string[] splittedProduct = value.Split(' ','.');
        foreach (String temp in splittedProduct)
        {
            output = output + " " + temp[0].ToString().ToUpper() + temp.Substring(1).ToLower();
        }
        output = output.Trim();
        return output;
    }

    public static string UrlEncode(this string input)
    {
        return input.Replace(" ", "%20");
    }
}
```

My output is just changing the first letter in the string only.

My string is this : Interviewer is very nice.technically strong also.

Comment: The problem is the second parameter of the `Split()` call. Remove it and write `string[] splittedProduct = value.Split(new char[] {' ', '.'});` instead

Comment: Still just capitalizing the first letter of the string only.

Comment: Hmmm, just checked it. It is working with your example string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are *studing* `string`s and thus out of the box `ToTitleCase` is not an option, be careful with `string + string`.

Concatenating `string`s is *time consuming* (especially in loop): each `+` creates a new `string`. Usually we use `StrignBuilder` for string building. So the *Title Case* implementation can be

```
public static string CapitalizeLetter(this string value) {
  // Do not forget to validate public methods' input
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value;

  // We know the size of string we want to build - value.Length 
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);

  bool toUpper = true;

  foreach (var c in value) {
    char add = c;

    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || c == '.')
      toUpper = true;
    else {
      if (char.IsLetter(c))
        add = toUpper ? char.ToUpper(c) : char.ToLower(c);

      toUpper = false;
    }

    sb.Append(add);
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reinventing the wheel.

[MS have already explained how](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/312890/how-to-convert-strings-to-lower-upper-or-title-proper-case-by-using-vi)

The link above shows how to use TextInfo and get the culture appropriate capitalized string on every word..  this is known as title case by this document.

In short it uses CultureInfo, TextInfo, and then uses the textinfo class to produce

`"this is a test"` to `"This Is A Test"`

Comment: in addition to this, there already is a UrlEncode method ready to use. Definitely  do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Capitalizes the first letter of each word in the string.

```
using System.Globalization;
string capitalized = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(“capitalizing the first letter of  some text”);
```

Here  The CultureInfo class is  from the `System.Globalization namespace`. From this class, you can get information about pretty much every possible culture out there, including a wide range of culture specific settings.

After the execution, capitalized string would have this value : “Capitalizing The First Letter Of Some Text” . which is exactly what we needed, right?

Suppose we want to set the current culture as of United States then,

```
TextInfo UsaTextInfo = new CultureInfo(“en-US”, false).TextInfo;
string capitalized = UsaTextInfo.ToTitleCase(“capitalizing the first letter of  some text”);
```

Comment: actually I want a more conventional way of solving this by using split() functions and for loops. Could you help me regarding this ?

Comment: Do you mean split each word into a string, and then capitalize?